# CSS Overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a site using Bootstrap and what I have is this:

[image: Site fullscreen]

However when i make the screen smaller I get this:

[image: Site smaller screen]

To make it easier on your eyes, I'll post my code on hastebin.

HTML: http://hastebin.com/cexizavule.xml

CSS: http://hastebin.com/tivuwonigu.css

So how would I go about making the elements not overlap? And what is the cause of overlapping elements?

If you dont want to click the links, Here.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>DarkHorizon</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">

<body>

<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class = "container">

        <a href = "/index.php" class = "navbar-brand">DarkHorizon</a>

        <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li><a href = "/index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href = "/gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                <li class = "dropdown">

                    <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Social Media<b class = "caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href = "https://www.facebook.com/adsfionsfwAFASFAS?ref=hl">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "http://steamcommunity.com/groups/DarkHorizonCommunity">Steam</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </li>


                <li><a href = "/about.php">Staff/About</a></li>



                <li><a href = "#contact" data-toggle ="modal">Apply/Contact us</a></li>

                <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {?>
                    <li class = "dropdown">

                        <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><?php echo ($_SESSION['username']) ?><b class = "caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "/user/loginhome.php">User Home</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </li>
                <?php }
                else{?>

                    <li><a href = "/login.php">Log in</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "/signup.php">Sign up</a></li>
                <?php
                }
                ?>



            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!--WEBSITE GOES HERE-->

<div class="navbarbg">
        <div class="usernavbar">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"><a href="loginhome.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="inbox.php">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>



<div class="pagedevwarn">
<div class='alert alert-danger'>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>! This page is still in development, Please be patient! </div>
</div>

<div class="title" align="center">
    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo ($_SESSION['username'])?>!</h1>
    <div class="line">
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="moneybox">
    <div class="dhmoneyz">
        <p><h4>Balance - $ 0.00</h4></p>


    </div>
</div>


<!--Website ends here-->

<div class = "navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class = "container">
        <p class = "navbar-text">Site built by Derk</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "modal fade" id = "contact" role = "dialog">
    <div class = "modal-dialog">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
                <h1>Contact us or apply for moderator!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                <form name ="contact-us" method = "post" action ="emailsent.php">
                    <label for = "contact-name" class = "col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "contact-name" placeholder = "Full Name">
                    <br />

                    <label for = "contact-email" class = "col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
                    <input type = "email" class = "form-control" name = "contact-email" placeholder = "you@example.com">
                    <br />

                    <label for = "contact-msg" class = "col-lg-2 control-label">Message:</label><br />
                    <textarea class = "form-control" rows = "8" name="contact-msg"></textarea>

                    <br />
                    <a class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.usernavbar{
    width: 140px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: fixed;
}

.navbarbg{
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
    width: 160px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 49px;

}

.pagedevwarn{
    width: 500px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 160px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.alert{
    border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar{
    border: none;
}

.title{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 80px;

}

.line{
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.moneybox{
    background-color: #adadad;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
}

.dhmoneyz{
    padding-top: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Include your code in the question; link rot.

Comment: **Link rot**.  Links are not good enough; the question must be useful to future readers.

Comment: @Daedalus Links and pictures provided, More than useful for future readers who are capable of using a mouse.

Comment: Last try; include the code in the question; links die and then the question becomes useless.  If you don't, I will vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not designed for a single set defined display.
It addresses multiple platforms, screen dimension, print layout,portrait/landscape etc.
You need to design a style for any of these you want your audience to be able to use.
It really is a language in itself.
And once you learn it then you will find each of these target platforms will have their own quirks that will break things in places even if you use defined W3C definitions.

It is well work learning, however for quick adaptation use jquery and jqueryUI widgets.
That in itself is not a fixall and you will still need to know what is going on.

Comment: So do you have any good references or tutorials on proper design?

Comment: One of my favorite sites is [CSS Tricks](http://www.css-tricks.com). They give example code for just about any styling question you have, so you can see how the HTML and CSS work together in your code.

Comment: This has been an invaluable tool when learning, and a good reference back point for all web technologies: http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: @TimHigham Okay, so apparently the site [changed](https://github.com/paulirish/w3fools/issues/50).

Comment: @Daedalus The site ? What site - all sites change, what exactly are you saying with your comment.

Comment: @TimHigham If you clicked the links, you'd know.